# For loop not running in postman Tests with pm.sendrequest

Tags: javascript, postman

EDIT: I had forgotten to pass the parameter to the function when calling it. Silly oversight.

I am a beginner with javascript, I have a bit more experience with java so this whole callback stuff in JS is new to me.

The below script is supposed to run in the "Tests" of postman.
The purpose of the script is to run pm.sendrequest once for each page in the paginated results (Spring boot framework) which the actual request has returned. I have tried using "await" here to let the sendrequest finish before extracting the results but the loop does not even run and I cant figure out why.

```js
// Get the response body as a JSON object
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
// Extract all the values from the "id" property in the "content" array of the response json
const firstPageValues = responseJson.content.map(obj => obj.id);
// create variables for expected and actual result assertion
const expectedSalesObjects = ["uuid"];
var returnedSalesObjects = [];
// store the value of totalPages and currentPage, for the pagination
const totalPages = JSON.parse(responseJson.pageable.totalPages);
let currentPage = 0;

console.log(totalPages);

const url = `${pm.environment.get("test-test-URL")}/api/v1/dashboard/test`;

function addValues (values) {
    values.forEach(function addSalesObjectsToArray(currentValue) {
    returnedSalesObjects.push(currentValue);
    });
}

addValues(firstPageValues);

async function getSalesObjectsFromPaginatedResponse(currentPage, totalPages) {
    while (currentPage <= totalPages) {
        const requestBody = {
            "test": "test",
            "test": "test",
            "fullTextSearch": pm.collectionVariables.get("searchTerm"),
            "pageNumber": i.toString()
        };
        
        const response = await pm.sendRequest({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: {
                mode: 'raw',
                raw: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
            }
        });
        
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        const salesObjects = responseJson.content.map(obj => obj.id);
        addValues(salesObjects);
        currentPage++;
    }
}

getSalesObjectsFromPaginatedResponse();

pm.test("Returned sales objects include test data", function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < expectedSalesObjects.length; i++) {
    pm.expect(returnedSalesObjects).to.include(expectedSalesObjects[i]);
    }
});

// teardown
    pm.collectionVariables.unset('searchTerm');
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You're not passing anything to `getSalesObjectsFromPaginatedResponse()` so the while loop will not work.